# How do you add a reference to a .NET Standard 2.0 dll from a .NET Standard 2.0 library?

Tags: c#, dll, reference, .net-standard-2.0

I want to compile a .NET Standard dll and provide it to customers.  However, i do not see how they can add a reference to the dll.  Visual studio only allows me to add solution references, as opposed to the typical solution references and system references.

I know NuGet is technically an option, but due to needing to sign certificates ($$$) it is out of the question as of now.

Comment: You do not need a code-signing certificate for nuget. You don't even need to strong-name it (although you probably should). Package references are the normal approach here, although note that you can use more feeds than just nuget, for example myget

Comment: Right-click Dependencies, choose "Add Project Reference..." and click Browse to reference the DLL?

Comment: @CodeCaster you are correct.  I was thrown off by the menu item being called Project Reference, that I didn't look into it further.  Thank you.